# base64 image in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm tryong to show a  base64 encoded image on a teig template this way:

```
 <img id="img.base-64" src="{{ data:image/png;base64, params.logo }}" />
```

but it doesn't work , the `params.logo` value is correct and if I hardcode it it works, I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Hi, can you try dump your params object and include it on your question

Answer (score 3):

Please turn on twig's debug mode, `{{ data:image/png;base64, ... }}` is definitely throwing errors. Either place the base part outside the twig statement or concat the string properly

```html
 <img id="img.base-64" src="data:image/png;base64, {{ params.logo }}" />
```

```html
 <img id="img.base-64" src="{{ 'data:image/png;base64, '~params.logo }}" />
```

Comment: I tried the first wat before post and it didn't work  and now I tried the second and it doesn't work too

Comment: What does not work? Are u sure `params.logo` is correctly base64-encoded? `{{ dump(params.logo) }}`